# F# 2d array index error

Tags: f#

The below code gives the error `The operator 'expr.[idx]' has been used an object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Consider adding further type constraints`. I think i have told it the type. What is wrong?

```
let board = Array2D.init 30 30 (fun x y -> 0)

let tickCell x y board : int[,]  =
    match board  with
    |board when board.[x].[y] = 0-> 1
    |board when board.[x].[y] = 1-> 0
    | _ -> -1

let board2 = Array2D.init 30 30 (fun x y -> tickCell x y board)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These small changes should get rid of the error:

1. Wrap the `board` parameter and type in parenthesis
2. Access the cell with `[x,y]`

   ```
   let tickCell x y (board : int[,])  =
       match board  with
       |board when board.[x,y] = 0-> 1
       |board when board.[x,y] = 1-> 0
       | _ -> -1
   ```

Comment: Note that with your original syntax, your type annotation was for the return type of the `tickCell` function, rather than the type of the `board` argument.